# sending and receiving data from android app to another

Tags: android, android-activity, sendinput

I'm building an android app , I need to contact with another app called Easy taxi .
this app need to fill some data like mobile number and destination, the problem is my app help blind people so I need to send this data from my app without the need to fill it and force the Easy taxi to confirm and request the taxi.
I read this article [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

but Easy taxi don't support to share even my Location , any Ideas to start from it ?!

Comment: Have a look at the API for the Easy taxi app, and see if there is any way around filling out forms.

Comment: first what you like to do is  impossible because easy taxi don´t provide this kind of data. if you like try to contact with easy taxi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wan't be able to communicate to other apps if they don't support this. If that app can't handle some intents or doesn't expose data via Content Providers, then there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

The application you mentioned must have a parsing mechanism to handle incoming data from other apps. This mechanism is called as URL scheme where an app listens for data coming from registered scheme and parses it to handle action. In your case, you should contact to Easy Taxi developers to find out if they have a URL scheme mechanism.